# Pointer to method without variable, how does this code work?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I came across some code I don't understand. In a class B there is a pointer to a method of a different class A but the pointer has no variable. How can I call this method in class B?
This is part of a larger project of someone else, i would like to preserve the existing code.

```
class A {
public:
  A *root() { return this; }
};

class B {
public:
  A *root();
};
```

I expected something like this

```
A *myA = root();
```

inside class B to work but i get linker error "undefined reference to ...". The question is more how this construction is called, what is it useful for and how to use it.

Comment: Would you be surprised if it was an `int`? Pointers are not special in that sense. Concerning the error you get, a little research should tell you what it means and how to fix it. That said, there is no "pointer to method" anywhere in the code you show. There is a method (or memberfunction) returning a pointer.

Comment: The method root() has no implementation. That's why you get a linker error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: `A*` ist just the return type of `B::root` if that’s what you are confused by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the comments standing, there is no implementation of `B::root()`. Maybe the code you have has beside the `.h` file a `.cpp` or `.hpp` file, where the implementation of `B::root()` stands - or there exists a library with it.

A valid implementation could be `A* B::root() { return new A(); }`. You can just grep for `B::root`.

To call `B::root()`, a simple `B b; A* as = b.root();` is enough. Same as with `A::root()`, where a simple call could be `A a; A* as = a.root();`

```
class A {
public:
  A *root() { return this; }
};

class B {
public:
  A *root();
};

A* B::root() { return new A(); }

int main() {
  A a;
  B b;
  A* asa = a.root();
  A* asb = b.root();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: By the way, it makes no difference if you write `A* a` or `A *a`, both are a pointer to A, at compile time the whitespace between is ignored/removed.  
Stroustrup uses `A* a` in his books.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. In hindsight it is obvious... The problem was there was just a declaration, the implementation was never done. I added that and it worked just as expected.